# Google Sign-In for a restricted list of users.

Tags: authentication, web, google-plus-signin

I have a simple web application but stores confidential information so I must secure it. The "web app" is no more than a table defined in html which is generated by a program.

Basically what I require is to use Google Sign-In for restricted list of users.

Example: Although I would have "Sign in With google", only

```
xyz@gmail.com,
abc@gmail.com & 
def@gmail.com
```

should have access.

How could that be done? I've searched but I haven't found any answers yet.

This is the API I was looking at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar. what i did was to have a local list of valid emails, so that before I send the request to google, i verify that the email is valid.

I actually also used it so that people couldn't register an account on my site, if their email wasn't pre-approved.

Comment: But wouldn't I need to retrieve the email from the google account first, before I could check with the local list of valid emails?

Comment: Ideally, yes. I think i did it so that users had to register, which is the process of giving your app access to some of their google account information. All future logins, the email is "pre-approved". to give a more detailed answer, i need to access my code (can't from where I am at the moment)

Comment: I see OK, I'll give it a try.